# How to obtain the inequality $\int |f|^2\log(|f|) \leq \frac{n}{4}\log\lVert f \rVert^2_{L^p} $ from Jensen's inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be a positive function with $\lVert f \rVert_{L^2}=1$. Let $p= 2n/(n-2)$.

How to obtain $\int |f|^2\log(|f|)  \leq \frac{n}{4}\log\lVert f \rVert^2_{L^p}$ from Jensen's inequality?

Here all norms and integrals are over a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $n$.

---

For context: this is a part of a proof of *logarithmic Sobolev inequality*. The log-Sobolev inequality follows by estimating the right hand side by $C\int |\nabla f|^2$.

Comment: The nature of manifold (even its dimension) is not relevant *at this step*; it can be any measure space. The reason for the exponent $2n/(n-2)$ is that Sobolev embedding will be used next. I added this bit of context to the post. Also, see [how to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)

Comment: @hardmath Sorry there was an extraneous "from" in the title. THe edit has made it clearer...

Comment: OK thanks, i will bear it in mind for future @Thisismuchhealthier....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality  $\int |f|^2 \log |f|=\int |f|^2 \cdot \frac{1}{p-2}\log |f|^{p-2} =  \frac{1}{p-2}\cdot\int |f|^2\log |f|^{p-2} \leq \frac{1}{p-2}\log (\int |f|^{p-2}\cdot |f|^2) = \frac{1}{p-2}\cdot \frac{p}{2}\log (\int|f|^p)^\frac{2}{p}=\frac{1}{p-2}\cdot \frac{p}{2} \log ||f||_p^2$

because $\frac{1}{p-2}=\frac{n-2}{4}, \frac{p}{2}=\frac{n}{n-2},$ so $\frac{1}{p-2}\cdot \frac{p}{2}=\frac{n}{4}$. We are done.

Comment: Thanks, the first $\leq$ to sign, are you applying the Jensen inequality from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form?? I think it's not that

Comment: The Jensen's inequality: $\phi$ is convex function and $\omega$ is non-negative and $L^1$ integrable satisfying $||\omega||_1=1$, then $\phi(\int f\cdot \omega)\leq \int \phi(f)\cdot \omega$

Comment: What can you say about the same integral if you don't assume $\|f\|_{L^2}=1$?